# Apache Tomcat mod ajp

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

I am trying a very simple setup with "demo00" successfully working on Tomcat and accessible by public IP:Port/demo00.  However when I try the virtual host below it fails to even find the website.  The website can be pinged, I do not want to serve any static content just take every request to "demo00".  Below is the Apache(2.4.54) virtual host second below is the Tomcat(9.0.64) configuration.
Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydemo.com
    ServerAlias mydemo.com
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/demo00 secret=123
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 

</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" address="::1" secretRequired="true" secret="123" 
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the `localhost` in httpd.conf plus the `address="::1"` in Tomcat. I'll bet httpd is trying to use an IPv4 address but Tomcat is only listening with IPv6. Try `address="localhost"` instead.

[The configuration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html) says that the default is to listen on all local interfaces. It does this by using `"localhost"` as the default address. When using `"localhost"`, the behavior depends upon the local DNS resolver. Some systems will return only `127.0.0.1` while others will return `127.0.0.1` *and* `::1`, and I'm not sure they will be returned in a predictable order (i.e. there is no DNS requirement that IPv4 precede IPv6 addresses in responses). Tomcat uses whatever Java returns from `InetAddress.getByName(String host)` which doesn't specify which IP will be returned if the hostname maps to multiple IPs.

It is highly likely that using `"localhost"` for *both* httpd *and* Tomcat will result in a connection which is reliable, since the DNS resolver is likely to be consistent if not predictable *a priori*. When in doubt, always use specific IP addresses in all places.

Incidentally, if you are building a new setup, I would highly recommend *against* using AJP. Instead, use mod_proxy_http and a plain-old HTTP(S) connector on the Tomcat side. You can read a presentation about [why to migrate from AJP to HTTP](https://tomcat.apache.org/presentations.html#latest-migrate-ajp-http) on the Tomcat web site.

Comment: @andrewJames I've updated my answer with a link to a presentation which lays out the case for migration from AJP to HTTP.

Comment: IIRC `address="localhost"` will only bind to the first address that resolves to `localhost`, whereas Apache Httpd will use both addresses in a round robin way.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I've updated my answer to address your concern.

Comment: With the change made still now working, just resolving to the default apache default page on the server.  I will migrate off but can I pursue this further.  It should work as edited?